# Database value show twice

Tags: php

Here is my code to retrive value from database

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM t_contact
                      WHERE id = {$project_details_id} LIMIT 1";
     $all_post_info1 = mysql_query($query, $connection);
     confirm_query($all_post_info1);
     $project_details = mysql_fetch_array(show_project_details($project_details_id));

     foreach ($project_details as $fieldname) {
        echo $fieldname . "</br>";
     }
```

And

```
function confirm_query($confirm_result) {

    if (!$confirm_result) {
        die("Database query failed1: " . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

And i get output twice for each field. There are 27 column in my database and i get 54 output.
For example, there are name, email column in database and my output shows like

```
name
name
email
email
```

Some please tell me what is wrong with this code.

Comment: You have left out some necessary information for debugging. Please post the code for `confirm_query()` and `show_project_details()`.

Comment: what is the size of `$project_details`

Comment: mysql_fetch_array($project_details_id, MYSQL_ASSOC); the default is to return both associative __AND__ enumerated keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By using MYSQL_BOTH (default), you'll get an array with both associative and number indices.

That's because your `$project_details` actually looks [something] like this:

```
$project_details = array(
  [0] => 'name',
  [name] => 'name',
  [1] => 'email',
  [email] => 'email'
);
```

Try specifying `MYSQL_ASSOC` in your [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) call.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this instead:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM t_contact
                        WHERE id = {$project_details_id} LIMIT 1";
$all_post_info1 = mysql_query($query, $connection);
confirm_query($all_post_info1);

while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($all_post_info1))
{

print_r($data);

}
```

mysql_fetch_assoc will return an associative array, which means an array where the keys are associated with the fields in your query. mysql_fetch_array will return an array with the fields as well as numeric key values, hence the double variables. I rarely ever use mysql_fetch_array, in almost every case mysql_fetch_assoc is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using foreach you should use while. As ex:

```
while($row = db_fetch_array($all_post_info1)) {
    echo $row[field_name];
}
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql_fetch_array()` by default returns keys in both indexed and associated format.

Use the `MYSQL_ASSOC` parameter to get only the associative version:

```
$project_details = mysql_fetch_array(show_project_details($project_details_id), MYSQL_ASSOC);
```

As is customary, I'll also remind you that **mysql functions are deprecated** and you should consider using e.g. [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$project_details = mysql_fetch_array($project_details_id);
```

With this line:

```
$project_details = mysql_fetch_array($project_details_id, MYSQL_ASSOC);
```